# New payment method not showing in order details

Tags: magento2, payment-methods

Currently i have created my custom payment method.
It's not showing as a payment method in the sales order email.
It showing as a payment method in the PDF and in the order view section .

If i place an order with another payment method it does show it. But i place an order with the new payment method it does not show it anywhere.

Comment: Can you post some code so we can see what you are doing?